# Convergence in Distribution using Moment Generating Functions

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Let $Y_{n} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \overline{X}$ where \begin{equation} \overline{X} = \frac{X_{1} + X_{2} + \cdots + X_{n}}{n} \end{equation} and the $X_{i}$ are independent. Use the moment generating functions technique to show that \begin{equation} Y_{n} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)  \ \ \text{as } n \to \infty \end{equation} Where $\xrightarrow{d}$ means converges in distribution. I got this question in my first year exam and since then I've not been able to work it out. The distribution of the $X_i$ I guess shouldn't matter but I can't think of how to work this out otherwise.

Comment: That does not look correct in general: in particular I would be doubtful about $Y_{n} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \overline{X}$.  Do you know more about the $X_i$?

Comment: I agree. It converges to the population mean by LLN provided they are i.i.d

Comment: Given that the moment generating functions exist (which is a big if) in a neighbourhood of zero, then there is a quick proof of this weaker case of the CLT. But we need a different statement: let $Y_n=\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ where $\mu,\sigma$ are the mean and standard deviations of the distribution.

Comment: @Henry, In the exam, no information was given about the $X_i$. The question before this in the exam was finding the MGF of the double exponential distribution $f(x) =\frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|}$ but this question was entirely separate.

Comment: If the $X_i$ are i.i.d. with a finite mean and variance (which would be implied by having an m.g.f. then $\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar X-\mu}{\sigma} \to N(0,1)$ in distribution.  In the case of your Laplace distribution you would have $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{2}$ so $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}} \overline{X}\xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$ as $n \to \infty$